# Why doesn't sympy solve polynomials correctly?

Tags: python, sympy

Maybe `sympy` shouldn't be used this way but the following is pretty self explanatory. My first equation isn't solved correctly because a degree 3 real polynomial must have real solution(s). And the result for the second polynomial is weird in the sense that `sympy` should know when the imaginary part is zero. Or what is the best way for returning only real solutions?

```
Python 3.5.0 (default, Sep 27 2015, 12:06:50) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sympy import *
>>> rho = symbols('rho')
>>> targetPoly = -0.0834311595130454*rho**3 - 0.0332128137292625*rho**2 + 0.00820751285938945*rho + 0.0014919833998052
>>> solve(targetPoly)
[]
>>> targetPoly = -0.083*rho**3 - 0.033*rho**2 + 0.008*rho + 0.001
>>> solve(targetPoly)
[-0.535556965628361 - 0.e-23*I, -0.0961083762029916 + 0.e-23*I, 0.234074980385569 - 0.e-23*I]
>>> exit()
```

Answer (score 2):

Removing the last decimal from each coefficient gives you a solution. To get rid of very small values use `.evalf(chop=True)`:

```
targetPoly = (-0.083431159513045*rho**3 - 0.033212813729262*rho**2 + 
              0.0082075128593894*rho + 0.001491983399805)
sol = solve(targetPoly)
[expr.evalf(chop=True) for expr in sol]
```

Result:

```
[-0.521021972648720, -0.133726616334545, 0.256662143545947]
```

`simplify()` also works:

```
[expr.simplify() for expr in sol]
```

Comment: Is there a reason for removing the last decimal? I don't really hv control over the coefficients, the particular example was from debugging a simulation n the coefficients are kind of random

Comment: I don't know if removing the last decimal will work in general, but `evalf(chop=True)` should always work for cases like this.

Comment: @mikemuller `[expr.simplify() for expr in sol]` not working